# After downloading the latest 64-bit ver., that .iso installed a 32-bit platform in my notebook!

Tags: 64-bit

I recently download the 64-bit version for my notebook. The notebook IS 64-bit, I checked it lots of times! But I use a pendrive and THAT .iso installed a 32-bit version. What should I do know? Where is the hidden the latest right 64-bit version? I thought to download and try to install the last 64-bit LTS to see if works!

Comment: Please edit your question and add a `uname -a` output to it, like stated in the first answer.

Answer (score 2):

If the result to the command:

```
uname -a
```

Contains **x86_64** then you are using the 64bit, else the 32.

Comment: Huh, it contains this string three times for me, to make me really sure I have a 64-bit system :-)

Comment: type uname --help to see all the options